# Using CSS3 fadein on .orbit-caption or individual elements inside .orbit-caption?

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, css-animations, orbit

I would love to be able to fadein certain individual elements inside my .orbit-caption (such as an h2 or a button). I've tried applying the CSS3 to both .orbit-caption and individual elements, but nothing works...any ideas?

Example markup (fadein applied to .orbit-container) is below.

```
<section id="carousel">
    <div class="row collapse">
        <div class="small-12 large-12 columns">
            <ul data-orbit>
              <li>
                <img src="image" />
                <div class="orbit-caption">
                    <h2 class="carousel">Hunting Coolers</h2>
                    <h3 class="subheader">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h3>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <img src="image" />
                <div class="orbit-caption">
                    <h2 class="carousel">Fishing Coolers</h2>
                    <h3 class="subheader">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h3>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

#carousel .orbit-container .orbit-slides-container > * .orbit-caption {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
color: #fff;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px 14px;
font-size: 0.875em;
-webkit-animation: fadein 5s;
-moz-animation: fadein 5s;
-o-animation: fadein 5s;
animation: fadein 5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your custom styles before you (generally) initialize Foundation. So for example if this is your custom style:

```
.the_coolest_orbit_style {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 5s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 5s;
    -o-animation: fadein 5s;
    animation: fadein 5s;
}
```

To make it work:

```
$(document).foundation('orbit', {
    orbit_transition_class: 'the_coolest_orbit_style'
    });

$(document).foundation();
```